# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to integrate firebase database into my project but i'm getting this error after adding this line to my app gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
```

error :

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;

Comment: Post the contents of `build.gradle` for module app.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AbirHasan the solution I found was to move the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line to the bottom of the file. Is not clear to me why this works.

Comment: [Firebase Android SDK docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) specifically says `ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to move the line

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line to the bottom of build.gradle the file.

Is not clear to me why this works, if this works please mark as answer somebody that has a better explanation.

Comment: The plugin analyzes your dependencies, that's why it has to be placed after the `dependencies` block. Otherwise it tries to import some defaults (maybe 9.0.0 version?) which conflicts with what you import in your dependencies block later.

Answer (score 0):

for me, removing 
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

worked. Helps this helps someone else

Comment: This plugin generates resources from `google-services.json`. Now you don't have the resources necessary for default and automatic Firebase configuration. If you configure `FirebaseApp` manually, that's OK. Considering this case is not documented in the official docs your answer just made every newbies' life difficult.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I had removed firebase from my app. The app worked somehow for a while with the line present. I removed the line and it worked. So basically i forgot to remove. And I put the answer here for any other person who has the same situation as mine. :-)